# How to enter incomplete or partial date with date module? (Day-Month-Year / Month-Year / Year)

Tags: 7, datetime

I have a content type A and it has a [date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) field.

I'm selecting `Day-Month-Year` for this date field. But not every content has a day and I want to select only `Month` and `Year` for these content.

If I select (enter) only month and year, it gives **error**:

> The value input for field Date is invalid: The value March 1979 does
>   not match the expected format.

I installed and tried the [Partial Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/partial_date) module but still couldn't do what I want although it says on the module page:

> This module provides date and time fields that allows any individual
>   component to be left blank, while still providing a sortable listing
>   of the fields.

How can I do that? I want to enter **full** date (`Day-Month-Year`) for some nodes and for some others **partial** date (only `Month-Year`) and maybe for some others only `Year`. **Isn't this possible?**

- `Day-Month-Year`
- `Month-Year`
- `Year`

(And also there is an **unsolved** issue about this: [Allow "fuzzy" granularity](https://www.drupal.org/node/259308).)

Comment: I would recommend also trying the partial date module again. It has worked for me in the past.

Comment: @rooby, thanks. I will try it again and I hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with one date field. But you can achieve it by adding two different date fields with different configuration i.e.:

- Date, Month and Year for **Date1** field.
- only Month and Year for **Date2** field.

Comment: I thought a similar method (one date field for per granularity; one field for day, one field for month and one field for year) but I think it's useless.

Comment: Yeah right!! Its useless. May be it can achieve thought custom coding or three different select list for date, month and year.

Answer (score 0):

The only way do to that is to set the widget type to `Select`, and omit the `Day` part, as seen in the below screenshot.

[image: date field settings]

UPDATE: I don't know why I haven't read the question completely; but Nikhil is right, the only way is create two `Date` components with different configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Create three different Date fields, using different date formats.
You can specify the Date entry option during Date field creation (click on More settings and values and choose Custom format in Date entry options, the custom input format for only a month would be F, for example)

[image]